# How to process the user generated price in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a requirement for a product order in woocommerce. I created a custom template for ordering the product. In that template, the user has to enter dimensions such as length, width, and height. Based on the dimensions they entered, there are some calculations performed using ajax, and the price is shown to the user. Below that there is an order button for ordering.

(now I created  a link which acts as button `<a id="order" href="site/checkout/?add-to-cart=96">Order</a>`)

The problem I have is that:

1. How can I work with the price generated based on the user input dimensions and work with the woocommerce normal working of cart and checkout with this generated price.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried [Measurement Price Calculator](https://www.woothemes.com/products/measurement-price-calculator/)?

Answer (score 0):

There's two hooks that might be of interest to you. The first is run when price is displayed on site:

```
function woo_dm_get_price($price, $product) {    
    // do something with $price
    return $price;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price', 'woo_dm_get_price', 999, 2 );
```

And the second is run when item is put in cart:

```
function woo_dm_add_cart_item( $item_data, $item_key ){
    $price = 123;
    // do something to calculate new price
    $item_data['data']->set_price( number_format( $price, 2 ) );
    return $item_data;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item', 'woo_dm_add_cart_item', 999, 2 );
```

Comment: Still problem exist. ie the user need to shop the other products when he go back and again enter new dimension. it will add with the previous ones.How to process this?

Comment: depends how you get the dimensions to the calculation inside woocommerce I guess. you will have to get the latest dimension within the above functions ...

Answer (score 0):

Please add this snippet in your function.php and it will work as per your need.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item', 'wolf_options_add_cart_item', 20, 1 );
function wolf_options_add_cart_item( $cart_item ) {

    if (isset($cart_item['_other_options'])) :
        if( isset($cart_item['_other_options']['product-price']) )
            $extra_cost = floatval($cart_item['_other_options']['product-price']);

        $cart_item['data']->adjust_price( $extra_cost );

    endif;

    return $cart_item;
}
```

this will work as per you need you just need to change the data you transfer from product page to in this line

```
if( isset($cart_item['_other_options']['product-price']) )
            $extra_cost = floatval($cart_item['_other_options']['product-price']);
```

Also you may try this plugin if you are not good in code: [WooCommerce Variable Pricing](https://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-variable-pricing-calculator-measurement-pricing/25814910)